Groovy - Load file and dynamically call function
I have 2 groovy scripts. Both are under /scripts.
From script npm.groovy I want to load script steps.groovy and dynamically call a function based on a Map that is provided.
npm.groovy:
void execute(){
  stepsApi = load("scripts/steps.groovy")

  Map steps = [upload:[number: "1", type: "module"]]

  steps.each { step, params ->
        stepsApi[step](params) <- Is this line correct?
    }
}

step.groovy:
void upload(Map params){

// ... some code here

}

I wonder if npm.groovy is correctly invoking the function from steps.groovy. Also, as steps is a Map, and I iterate over it, is params a Map? If not, what should the type be in upload function?
Below is the error when the above is run:
 groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: upload for class: groovy.variant.npm.Script6


Run the code and determine, if the result is correct to your definition.
If you have a concrete problem, then [edit] the question and explain
what errors you get.

added the error hope is clearer now what the question is!

Found the solution. To dynamically call a function we can use the below:
void execute(){
  stepsApi = load("scripts/steps.groovy")

  Map steps = [upload:[number: "1", type: "module"]]

  steps.each { step, params ->
        stepsApi."$step"(params)
    }
}

